# Ionic pro framework error InAppBillingService does not exist - Android Build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am getting the error below in ionic pro while I am generating Android build.

But in my mac environment it's working fine and successfully generating debug apk.

> error: package com.android.vending.billing does not exist import
>   com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService;

*Please find attached screenshot for more details.*

Thank you in advance!

[image]